# JAWS not reading label associated with select in Chrome

Tags: w3c, jaws-screen-reader

When we use JAWS and navigate to this select it doesn't read this label Actor, only reads currently selected value. It works well with IE and FF.

```
      <label for="actor">Actor:</label>
      <select id="actor">
      <option label="Select">Select</option>
      <option label="1">1</option>
      <option label="2">2</option>
      <option label="3">3</option>
      <option label="4">4</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one tag with id="actor" in the DOM?

Comment: No, I also tried on different pages and result is same. Example

http://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls#select

Comment: @BenjaminTalic You're wrong

Comment: This must be a Chrome/JAWS issue because the only way to get it to read the label was to add aria-labelledby